# How To Change the collation of an entire database?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS with typeorm
I have tthis entity entity to extends from it after for another entities

```
export abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'updated_at' })
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

So the problem is :

- I worked with this entity with typeorm **V 0.2** and i have this collation type for ID **utf8mb3_general_ci**
- I did a migration of typeorm from **V 0.2** to V **0.3**. (upgrade nest v7 -- v9)
- After every new migration (adding tables) that extends the table in above, and that contain **RELATION** (one_to_many,...) with tables that was created with typeorm **V 0.2**
- I have this error **Referencing column 'tableName' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK' are incompatible**

After invetigation i found that the **collation type** of Id extended from AbstractEntity  is **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
**
In this case I have a problem that the id from the FK of the old table (**utf8mb3_general_ci**) and the new table is (**utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**), i think that way i ahve this problem

So i wanna know to change the collation type in the entire database from **utf8mb3_general_ci** to the new one **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci?

Or is there any other solutions?**

**Thank you!!**

I try this command but it doesnt work
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Comment: Your problem is CHARACTER SET, not collation. *I try this command but it doesnt work* It works. But it effects only the objects creation and does not alter the objects and data which already exists. You must alter separate tables, their columns and your data explicitly. Or you may create new structure with needed charset/collation and copy your data to it.